# Grabbing EMF meter magnifies signal 10fold

Tags: emf

I have a [Tenmars tm‑195](https://www.radmeters.com/Tenmars-TM-195.html).  Holding it in my hand arm's length, still, I read \$2 \mu W / cm^2\$.  In exactly the same spot, without me holding it, I read 10 times lower, \$0.2 \mu W / cm^2\$.  I can reproduce this consistently.  As far as I can tell, the main source of EMF should come from standard city electricity wires from the streets, but I am not sure.

Is this strange behavior normal?  What does it mean?

Comment: You have met the antenna, and it is you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any conductive object has a strong effect on the electric fields around it. One of the effects is that fields are concentrated where the curvature of a conductive is greatest.

You are basically an animated bag of salt water, and you modify the electric fields wherever you go. The curvature of your body is greatest at the ends of your limbs, including your hands. So putting an E-field meter there is going to measure those effects.

There is nothing surprising about this.

Comment: The instructions say to hold this in your hand.  Should I deduce that that is wrong, and the right way to measure is to not hold it?  Presumably the instructions are meant for situations like mine.

Comment: Well, do you care about the field measurements near your body, or the measurements when you aren't there? Obviously, there are no health effects from the latter.